# Fancybox works on local computer but it doesnot work after uploading it to webserver

Tags: jquery, fancybox, localhost

I am using fancybox to play youtube video. it works fine on my localhost but it doesn't work on live website after clicking an image video should open in fancybox, instead it opens in youtube.com.

Pls suggest some solutions. Please my test page on

[Link for your reference](http://www.projectsstream.com/test/fancybox-with-video/test.html)

Comment: Check the paths to your js and css files. If you are not sure, use absolute paths. Right now your pointers return 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();//default action of the event will not be triggered.
            $("a[@rel*=fancyvideo]").fancybox({
                overlayShow: true,
                frameWidth: 640,
                frameHeight: 360
            });
        });
    </script>
```

hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

Your script and css calling path are incorrect, please call them by absolute path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.pngFix.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/fancy.css"/>
```

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```